# Opencart 1.5 (ocStore): after coping to another hosting I see an infinite load of main page

Tags: opencart, google-cloud-platform

This is not first time when I see this infinite loading after copying my OpenCart shop - but if I look to source of page in browser - I see the code and loaded resources at `Network` tab at Chrome. After maybe 10 minutes of loading sometimes I can see my site that looks like without CSS.

My steps: creating new VM at Google Cloud, installation of mysql (+ creation user & "grant all"), installation of apache2, phpmyadmin, copy files from old hosting and at `config.php` change internal path.

At `/var/log/apache2/error.log` no one error. `Apache` and `MySQL` is working. VM is fast enough and CPU with RAM not loaded too much. Restart of VM does not help.

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, this is caused by a typo in the config file for the HTTP_SERVER. Make sure it's formatted as http://www.domain.co.uk/ , anything else could cause the loop.